# How can I know if a number is Prime using a boolean 2d Array?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am working on a code to be able to solve The Sieve of Eratosthenes approach using a boolean 2D array that creates a Chart Map using user's input and then reading each index value and if its a prime number return true statement, after that to print one more time the Chart Map but this time only showing the Prime Numbers, this is my code so far but I am stuck on the checking if the value is prime part:

```
public class Runner {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);    //INPUT STREAM TO LET USER MODIFY THE ARRAY
    System.out.println("We are about to display The Sieve of Eratosthenes");  
    System.out.println("Please Input the desired number: ");
    int n= sc.nextInt(); //User inputing desire number example: 5 would create a 5x5 Matrix
    int charting = 0; //Variable to populate Chart with numbers 1 through n
    int prime = 0; //Variable to count how many prime numbers there are inside of Matrix
    boolean[][] Chart = new boolean[n+1][n+1]; //Initializing Array with given input
    //Nested Loop to Populate with Rows and Columns 2D ARRAY
    for(int i = 1; i < Chart.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 1; j < Chart[i].length; j++) {
            charting++; //Variable incrementing per each free space inside the array
            //If Structure to find if each number is prime or not
            if(i-1 % i == 0) {
                Chart[i][j] = false;
            }
            else {
                Chart[i][j] = true;
                
            }
            
            }
            
            
        }
    
    System.out.println("Total Numbers In The Chart: " + charting);
    System.out.println("Chart Map Before Getting The Prime Numbers: ");
    PrintChartPreCode(n,n);
    System.out.println("Prime Numbers on The Chart: " + prime); 
}

//METHOD TO PRINT THE CHART MAP
public static void PrintChartPreCode(int rows, int columns) {
    int x = rows;
    int y = columns;
    for(int i = 0; i < x; i++) { //ROWS
        for(int j = 0; j < y; j++) { //COLUMNS
            System.out.print((j + y*i + 1) + "|"); 
            
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
 }
```

}

Comment: In the Sieve of Eratosthenes, there is no  test of the type `if ( isPrime (n) )`.   And it is not clear why you need a 2D array.

Comment: There are more comments on this question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72605487/how-to-create-the-sieve-of-eratosthenes-using-a-2d-boolean-array